# Disabling visual studio reload message

Tags: visual-studio

I use emacs to edit source code, and use visual studio ide to compile. However, I see the following message in visual studio when the source is modified.

http://img201.imageshack.us/img201/7264/reload.jpg

Can I disable this message with the default action of reloading?

Comment: I find this a strange way to develop your applications. Perhaps you should use MSBuild.exe from the command-line instead of using Visual Studio only for compiling your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes: 
"Tools" - "Options" - "Environment" - "Documents" - "Auto-load changes when saved" (VS2008)

[image]

Comment: @ur : Thanks, you'd better add "Tools" as the starting point.

Answer (score 0):

After your build, before you switch to emacs, close the files. This prompt only occurs for open files. You can use the "close all" command to do so quickly.